# Using custom methods with SQlite.NET Filter predicates

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net

We are using SQLite.NET (1.5.231) in a Xamarin project

We execute Get queries like this

```
var result = await db.Table<T>().Where(query).ToListAsync();
```

Where db is a `SQLiteAsyncConnection` and query is a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

If I pass something like this as query it works

```
(intervention.EndDate == null && intervention.StartDate == day) || 
intervention.EndDate == null && intervention.StartDate <= day && day <= DateTime.Now.Date
```

However I'd prefer to wrap the logic up in a function and pass it like this

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Intervention>> GetAMonthsInterventionsAsync(int month, int year)
{
        var interventions = await this.dataProviderService.GetAsync<Intervention>(
                                                i => ShouldInterventionBeConsideredInMonth(month, year, i),
                                                false);
    
        return interventions;
 }

private bool ShouldInterventionBeConsideredInMonth(int month, int year, Intervention intervention)
{
    DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1).StartOfDay();
    DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)).EndOfDay();

    bool inMonth = false;

    if (intervention.StartDate <= endOfMonth && intervention.EndDate != null && intervention.EndDate >= startOfMonth)
    {
        // Intervention starts before the month ends AND ends after the month starts
        inMonth = true;
    }
    else if (intervention.StartDate <= endOfMonth && intervention.EndDate == null)
    {
        inMonth = true;
    }

    if (intervention.IsDeleted)
    {
        inMonth = false;
    }

    return inMonth;
}
```

That fails with a

```
**System.NotSupportedException:** 'Cannot compile: Parameter'
```

This is because SQLite cannot understand GetAMonthsInterventionsAsync. How can I use this kind of abstraction with SQlite?

Comment: That's is too complicate for SQLite to understand

Comment: I realise that so I wondering how other people encapsulate that kind of logic. I guess the only way is it to concatenate a number of SQL statements